# Android application stops working

Tags: android, android-intent

It doesn't say that it has any errors, just that, when i try to launch it, it stops and it displays the following message:

> "Unfortunately, LifeSaver has stopped".

activity_saver.xml:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    tools:context=".Saver" >

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button1"
        android:layout_width="60dp"
        android:layout_height="60dp"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:background="@drawable/circle" 
        android:onClick="sendMessage" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button2"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_alignRight="@+id/button1"
        android:layout_marginTop="68dp"
        android:text="Button"
        android:onClick="schimba" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Saver.java:

```
public class Saver extends Activity {

    Button panica = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button1);
    Button b;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_saver);
        b = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button2);
    }


    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.saver, menu);
        return true;
    }

    public void sendMessage(View v) {
        panica.setBackgroundColor(Color.BLUE);
    }

    public void schimba (View v){
        Intent i = new Intent (Saver.this, MainActivity.class);
        startActivity(i);
    }
}
```

activity_main.xml:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    tools:context=".MainActivity" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView2"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/hello_world" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

MainActivity.java:

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.saver, menu);
        return true;
    }
}
```

activity_main.xml:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    tools:context=".MainActivity" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView2"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/hello_world" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: Your errors will show up in logcat.

Comment: It says "at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2097)" I don't understand it....

Answer (score 2, accepted):

currently you are initializing `button1` before setting layout for `Saver` Activity so move initialization of Views after `setContentView` of Activity as:

```
 Button b,panica;  //<<< Declare here

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_saver);
    b = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button2);
    panica = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button1);   //<< initialize here
}
```

and also make sure you have registered both Activity in `AndroidManifest.xml`

Comment: thanks, it worked!! :D I didn't think that such a small thing could make such a mess

Answer (score 1):

```
Button panica = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button1);
Button b;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_saver);
    b = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button2);
}
```

You can't initialize `panica` outside of the `onCreate` method (your layout hasn't been set yet).

So change that code to this:

```
Button panica;
Button b;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_saver);
    b = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button2);
    panica = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button1);
}
```